# NProbability not reliability analysis?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have 2  random independent variables x and y. 
x is the strength of a bar and y is the force applied to the bar.
x has a Lognormal distribution with mean 10. and standard deviation 2.
y has a Normal distribution with mean 5. and standard deviation 2.
The bar will fail if we have x-y = 0.
How to calculate the probability of the bar to fail?
I tried the following and expected that probability of fail would be 0.032.

```
NProbability[
 x - y == 0.,
 {
  x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[10., 2.],
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[5., 2.]
  },
 Method -> {"MonteCarlo"}
 ]
```

Comment: I think your condition should be `y > x` (or equivalently `x - y < 0`).  That is, the bar will fail when the applied force is *greater*.  Your current statement is that the bar will fail when the applied force is *exactly equal* to its strength, which for smooth distributions will happen with probability zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two related problems.  The first is that `NProbability` finds the probability of a condition being met.  However, your condition `x - y == 0` is only true when `x` and `y` are *exactly* equal, which happens with probability zero.

Fixing the condition to `y > x` (and using the default `Method`), we get a probability of:

```
NProbability[
 y > x,
 {
  x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[10, 2], 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[5, 2]
 },
 AccuracyGoal -> 30
]

(* 0. *)
```

Practically zero, much lower than you expect.  I think you have a second problem, which is that `LogNormalDistribution` does not do what you expect it to.  It is the distribution of `Exp[x]`, where `x` is normally distributed with the parameters given to `LogNormalDistribution`.  Therefore in general the mean and standard deviation of the distribution will not be the numbers you put in.

We can use `Solve` to find out what the parameters should be:

```
soln = NSolve[Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}[LogNormalDistribution[a, b]]] == {10, 2}
 && b > 0, {a, b}, Reals]

(* {{a -> 2.28297, b -> 0.198042}} *)
```

Now we can use `NProbability` again (without any special options):

```
NProbability[y > x, {
 x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[a, b] /. First@soln,
 y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[5, 2]
}]

(* 0.0321748 *)
```

And this time we get exactly what you expect.

Comment: I had overlooked the point regarding the mean and standard deviation the first time I read the OP's question. I'm glad you expanded your comment into a full answer: that's an excellent explanation; I hope the OP will appreciate it as well.